# Messaging between multiple UnicastProcessor in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I try to messaging via UnicastProcessor and then write the received message into mongoDb.
I have created a handle where I catch a session. done like this and it works:

In handle method i have now:

```
@Component
public class NotifikaceWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotifikaceWebSocketHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    public UnicastProcessor<String> messagePublisher;

    @Autowired
    public UnicastProcessor<String> messagePublisherDb;

    public Flux<String> outputMessages;
    public Flux<String> outputMessagesDb;

    public NotifikaceWebSocketHandler () {
        logger.info("vytvoreni unicastprocessor a napojeni fluxu se zpravami");
        this.messagePublisher = UnicastProcessor.create();
        this.messagePublisherDb = UnicastProcessor.create();
        this.outputMessages = this.messagePublisher.publish().autoConnect();
        this.outputMessagesDb = this.messagePublisherDb.publish().autoConnect();
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(){
        return RouterFunctions.route(
                GET("/"),
                request -> ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new ClassPathResource("templates/index.html")))
        ).and(RouterFunctions.route(
                GET("/webSocketConnection.js"),
                request -> ServerResponse.ok().body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new ClassPathResource("static/webSocketConnection.js")))
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {    
        session.receive().subscribe(m -> {
                    String s = m.getPayloadAsText();

                    logger.info("received via subscribe, sent to unicastprocessor using onNext:{} ", s);
                    messagePublisherDb.onNext(s);
                    messagePublisher.onNext(s);
                }
                , err -> {
                    logger.error("subscribe error");
                    logger.error(err.getMessage());
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
                , () -> {
                    logger.info("end subscribe");
                }
        );      

        return session.send(outputMessages.map(s -> {
            logger.info("sending a large letter from a flux connected to an unicastprocessor: {}", s.toUpperCase());
            return session.textMessage(s.toUpperCase());
        }));

    }

    public Flux<String> getOutputMessagesDb() {
        return outputMessagesDb;
    }
}
```

and in service:

```
@Service
public class NotifikaceService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotifikaceService.class);

    @Autowired
    NotifikaceRepository notifikaceRepository;

    @Autowired
    NotifikaceWebSocketHandler notifikaceWebSocketHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init () {

        notifikaceWebSocketHandler.getOutputMessagesDb().flatMap(s -> {

            logger.info("save {}", s);
            final Notifikace notifikace = new Notifikace();
            notifikace.setGuid(UUID.randomUUID());
            notifikace.setText(s);
            return notifikaceRepository.save(notifikace);

        }).doOnError(error -> {
            // Handle Error here
        }).subscribe();

    }
}
```

After submitting from the form, the console:

```
2019-11-22 22:29:10.905  INFO 6248 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.o.a.n.NotifikaceWebSocketHandler       : received via subscribe, sent to unicastprocessor using onNext:test 
2019-11-22 22:29:10.906  INFO 6248 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.o.a.n.NotifikaceWebSocketHandler       : sending a large letter from a flux connected to an unicastprocessor: TEST
```

I need to catch the sent message in service and save it in db

I want to write a message to mongoDb, but since there is no repository in the hand, it simply won't work.
I would like to create a second unicastprocessor where I would send the message in service which will have the @PostConstruct method I would save it to db.
Unfortunately I am not doing it. Does anyone have any idea why it shouldn't work like this, or did anyone do something like that?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: several questions, what is session.receive() i can't find that in the WebSocketSession javadocs. And what do you expect the `onNext` method to do?

Comment: This is how you usually use UnicastProcessors, you need to obtain the sink and then transmit using the `next()` method https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_safely_produce_from_multiple_threads_by_using_the_sink_facade

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I tried that. Unfortunately, when I put on service subscribe (), it doesn't catch the processor message.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean ”put on service subscribe?”

Comment: the goal is to save what I get from WebSocketSession to a database. Since it is not possible to call the repository directly in WebSocketHandler and save it to the database, I created a service where I have the @PostConstruct method. In this method I have subscribe to UnicastProcessor.

Comment: you need to seriously read up on Webflux. First of all https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketHandler.html read this in how you use Websocket handlers.

Comment: In your handle method you should NOT subscribe, you should obtain the sink from the UnicastProcessor and then use the sink to push a new messages. Good luck

Comment: I tried sink, but I don't know how to use it. The handler I created this sink by: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_safely_produce_from_multiple_threads_by_using_the_sink_facade

Need to create two unicast processors? And two outputMessages?

Comment: if you don't know how to use processors, then dont use them. They are complicated and you seem to be struggling with the basics of webflux. As it says here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_do_i_need_a_processor do you actually need one? Maybe you should do something simpler, like websocket, to database, and ignore the unicastprocessor.

Comment: I need to send messages to more clients at the same time. That's why I found the unicastprocessor suitable.

Comment: Does that mean it won't be saved to mongoDb like this or am I doing something wrong?